# How to run NordVPN and Xampp together

Tags: windows, xampp, vpn

I've got Xampp installed on a win10 machine and I've also got Nordvpn installed on the same machine. When Nordvpn is active, I can't access site from outside my network nor locally. When not active I of course have access and pages load fine.

How would I set this up to still have access to pages from outside my network while running Nordvpn?